# Suspend resume problem in Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: suspend, lenovo

I have installed Ubuntu 18.04 alongside Windows 8.1 in my laptop Lenovo Z50-70. When I suspend the laptop either by command `PM_DEBUG=true pm-suspend` or closing the lid it suspends properly but when waking up login screen freezes and none of the keys are giving response. Also mouse click won't respond. Any help is appreciated. How to debug this kind of issue?

Comment: Please move this comment up into the question.  Also, please explain where that command was placed.

Comment: I ran that command in terminal as root to see what went wrong in /var/log/pm-suspend.log. But it is fine when the system suspends but the problem is in resuming.

Answer (score 2):

I fought with this problem on my Lenovo Thinkpad for a good while.  I do not have a nvidia card.  From what I gathered after a few days of reading, there is some kind of issue with 4.15 kernels and above with Intel Celeron N processors.  I tried a user suggested patch (4.15.024), tried the nouveau.modeset=0, and for a while reverted back to Ubuntu 17.10

The only clear fix I have applied is rolling back the kernel to 4.14.59 (SEE UPDATE AT END OF MSG).  My laptop now goes into suspend correctly (via power button or laptop lid closing), and it comes out of suspend correctly.

An app called UKUU allows installing additional Kernel's.  You may have to edit your GRUB settings to define the default grub.  Long explanation that I am not the best to provide.

use of suspend extremely important to me on this device.  small/low powered machine takes a long time to boot.  If I can open and close it and carry it around in suspend, Ubuntu 18.04 is great.

-Further info gleaned from filing a bug report, upgraded kernel to 4.18 and now everything is working fine (suspending and resuming from suspend without problems).

Answer (score 1):

After some research, I have found that you can solve this error, at least for a Dell Inspiron 5557 like mine, by adding the following parameter to the kernel command line, "nouveau.modeset=0" editing the grub configuration file.

```
$ sudoedit /etc/default/grub
```

Insert the command to the line as follows:
"GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="nouveau.modeset=0 quiet splash""
press ^O, save the file, press ^X and run:

```
$ sudo update-grub
```

Reboot.

Comment: I tried your solution. Now laptop will display black blank screen after resume.